# Karate / Post Request : Unable to pass random generator variable in json payload

Tags: karate

I am trying to create Karate feature file for API Testing.
It is a post request and we have to pass random number for 1 field i.e. order in request payload every time.
Now, I am trying to use this function in the same feature file  to pass that random generated value in json payload before sending post request.

Could someone please have a look at my feature file and help.
Thanks

[image]

Also, Is there a way if i want to pass this same random value for a json payload created as a separate request.json payload file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `requestPayload` is within double quotes, so it became a string.

Here's an example that should get you going. Just paste it into a new `Scenario` and run it and see what happens.

```
* def temp1 = 'bar'
* url 'https://httpbin.org/anything'
* def payload = { foo: '#(temp1)' }
* request payload
* method post
```

And please read the documentation and examples, it will save a you a lot of time.